# Search Date Field with a Custom Format

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, date-format

I'd like to return all entries that are in the future - but based only on the day of the week and time. I've got it working with just %H:%i (Hours/Minutes), but can't get it to respect the day of the week.

Is this possible?

Can you choose a custom date format of a channel field to check against?

**Thanks in advance!**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="CHANNEL" search:starttime=">{current_time format='%w %H:%i'}"}
     {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Can you specify a bit further: "respect the day of the week"

Answer (score 0):

The weekday is irrelevant to ***CURRENT_TIME*** since `current_time` is now. How it's presented on the *front end* is determined by the date formatting code on the backend, but since you are not manipulating `current_time` it's of no consequence here.

Of course, all of that is academic, because if you truly want to…

> …display all entries that are in the future…

…then what you really want is the built-in mechanism of `show_future_entries = 'yes'`. This will accomplish the stated goal without having to create a custom search every time the template's loaded. The docs for `show_future_entries` are [**here**.](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#show-future-entries)

If you click through to that link, you should also scroll down to the `start_on` parameter and you will see that its limitations include an inability to be dynamic: you MUST enter a fully realized date. That said, you could include some PHP to generate your relative future date, and achieve some arbitrary future entry display that way, but that's not what you asked. ;-)

Or am I missing something in your question? HTH.